# html теги и атрибуты, jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Добрый вечер!
У меня есть html (часть)

```html
 <a name="2529360"></a>
                <div class="card card-hover card-visited job-link card-logotype">
                    <div class="logo-img">
                        <img width="100" height="50" alt="DataArt"
                             src="//i.work.ua/employer_design/6/6/5/27665_company_logo_5.png">
                    </div>
                    <h2><a href="/jobs/2529360/" title="Senior Java Engineer, вакансия от 03.02.17">Senior Java
                        Engineer</a></h2>
                    <div>
                        <span>DataArt</span>&nbsp;
                        <span data-content="Компания использует услугу «Бизнес-размещение» Подлинность компании подтверждена Work.ua <a href='/help/?id=177' class='bp-more' target='_blank'>Подробнее<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span></a>"
                              data-toggle="popover"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-business text-success "></span></span>&nbsp;
                        <span class="label label-vip ">VIP</span>&nbsp;
                        <span class="text-muted ">· </span>
                        <span>Харьков<span class="text-muted">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</span>3 ч. назад</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-muted overflow"> Полная занятость. Опыт работы от 2 лет. Высшее образование.<br>
                        Requirements&nbsp;— Mandatory Excellent knowledge of&nbsp;Java. Experience in&nbsp;development
                        of&nbsp;applications using…<a href="/jobs/2529360/"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></p>
                </div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как по такому html я могу получить всю информацию о вакансии с помощью библиотеки jsoup? Если я пытаюсь следующим образом

```
 Elements elements =  doc.getElementsByTag("h2");
        for (Element elem:elements) {
           System.out.println(elem.text());
```

Я получаю только название вакансии, без зарплаты (если она указана, конечно), названия конторы и т.п.
Спасибо!

Comment: вы понимаете, что именно делает ваш код?

Comment: У меня с этим сложности. h2 - это тег для заголовка 2го уровня. Я получаю заголовки - названия вакансий.